# Issue in getting difference between 2 lists

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to find the difference between two lists - charLs and rigLs but as I tried to use the list and set methods as I found online, it is giving me very different results.

In the example below, I should be seeing female01 and elderly01 in the diff1 results but yet I am getting male01
Even as I switched around the set, like in diff2, this time round it is giving the list of the 3 rigs that was in the scene.

Did tried out the `list(set(..)^set(..))` and using of `difference` as well as something like `[x for x in rigLs if x not in charLs]` still it is not working.

Not sure if this is because the rigs created using the in-house modules (those under `|SceneGrp|characterRig`) and thus the portion that involves the listRelatives are giving off problems

Any other ways in which I can get the difference?

```
pubObj = cmds.ls(type = "publishedRef")
rigLs = []
for item in pubObj:
    nameSplit = item.split(':')
    rigLs.append(nameSplit[0])

grpNode = cmds.ls("SceneGrp", type=grpNode.name())
check = cmds.objExists("|SceneGrp|characterRig")
charLs = cmds.listRelatives("|SceneGrp|characterRig", c=True)

# Assumingly the following are the items appended into the list
# rigLs : [u'male01', u'female01', u'elderly01']
# charLs :[u'male01']

diff1 = list(set(charLs)-set(rigLs))
# Results : [u'male01']

diff2 = list(set(rigLs)-set(charLs))
# Results : [u'male01', u'female01', u'elderly01']
```

Comment: I think you need `set.symmetric_difference(t)` as per the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Comment: if i try your example lists a get different result

In [3]: list(set(charLs)-set(rigLs))
Out[3]: []

In [4]: list(set(rigLs)-set(charLs))
Out[4]: [u'female01', u'elderly01']

problem is in your items

Comment: @TomDalton Yes I did try that out as well `list(set(charLs)^set(rigLs))` but it is not working too

Comment: Can you post a *minimal* example of what's not working? E.g. it sounds like the problem is actually that `charLs` and `rigLs` don't contain what you think they contain.

Comment: @farincz I would say the list would works of the items within are inputted in manually. But the moment I tried to run the code as a whole like what I pasted, the results differs greatly

Comment: `>>> a = [u'male01', u'female01', u'elderly01']
>>> b = [u'male01']
>>> set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
set([u'female01', u'elderly01'])
>>> 
` seems to work...

Comment: @TomDalton Please see the previous post that I commented to farincz. It is somewhat hard to post a minimal example as half the items (which is required in the code) are created with in-house modules.

Comment: Then how do you expect us to help you? Your question is essentially "I have two lists, I  don't know what's in them and an operation that should work if the data is X doesn't work." We have proven that if the data is X, then the symmetric difference does work, so the problem is with your data.

Comment: Are you still experiencing problem? I tried your code with the exact (simulated) inputs on my machine, and it worked as expected.

Comment: @TomDalton Well, pardon me then. I had thought that there may just be another way of doing it rather than the solutions I have found online or the solutions as depicted here. Thanks again for any given help rendered!

Comment: @kartikg3 Yes I am still experiencing the same issue. I would say it is not due to the 'pythonic' modules but rather the `listRelatives` and the in-house modules that was used, causing some rather interesting issues. At least the issues was somewhat narrowed down.

Comment: If you provide a sample dataset, your latest code and some test results, i can take a look and help out, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following is slightly optimized so that we create only once the set on the elements of the second list

```
In [64]: l1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
In [65]: l2 = [8,3,6]
In [66]: [elt for l2s in [set(l2)] for elt in l1 if elt not in l2s]
Out[66]: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9]
In [67]:
```

a function to do the same

```
def l1_minus_l2(l1, l2):
    return [elt for l2s in [set(l2)] for elt in l1 if elt not in l2s]
```

if you prefer to return an iterator

```
def l1_minus_l2(l1, l2):
    return (elt for l2s in [set(l2)] for elt in l1 if elt not in l2s)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I am sure it will helps out in my code. But at the moment, it would seems that the in-house modules is somewhat not working with the maya `listRelatives` which is causing the problem - not able to list out the differences of the two lists